# XNA displaying data from text file to array

Tags: arrays, xna, streamreader, text-files

right now, I'm going to make a scoreboard for my game.
the program will displayed data from text file.

in the program, I have arrays of string for player name and score.

this is my streamreader code look like :

```
 public void ReadHighScores()
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("highscore.txt"))
            {

                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] parts = line.Split(',');
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        highScores.PlayerName[i] = parts[0];
                        highScores.Score[i] = parts[1];
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            //IntializeHighScores();
            //WriteHighScores();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle unexpected exception
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the file
        }
    }
```

and this is how I draw that scoreboard :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, i + 1 + ". " + highScores.PlayerName[i].ToString()
           + "......" + highScores.Score[i].ToString(), new Vector2(350, 150 + 50 * (i)), Color.Red);
         }
```

when I run the game. the succesfully read the data from text file. but it only displayed last data in the text file.

my text file contain :

```
 Alpha, 3500
 Beta, 3600
 Gamma, 2200
 Delta, 3400
 Epsilon, 3600
```

and the program only display the last data in loop like :

```
Epsilon 3600
Epsilon 3600
Epsilon 3600
Epsilon 3600
Epsilon 3600
```

what must I do to display all data from the text file, not only the last one ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right, but for every line you read from the file, you assign each member of the high scores array with the same data (in the `for` loop). You need to figure out which line you are on (just have a counter that gets incremented on every loop of the file reading loop) and only update the respective `PlayerName` and `Score`.

Comment: No, in the `while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)` loop, take the for loop out, and use a variable to track how many times the while loop has run. Use that to index the array instead.

Comment: so I need to add for loop above the while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)...?

Comment: hmm, I still not get it. can you give an code example of it...?

Comment: Create a variable `i` at the top of `ReadHighScores`. Take out the for loop in `ReadHighScores`. At the end of the `while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)` loop body, put `i++;`.

Comment: ow yeah. it works!!!
thanks slugonamission.

by the way,how about comparing the score. so it display the highest one in the top...?